# Angular create table from objects

Tags: angularjs

From a Rest Api I am getting the following:

```
{
 "headers": ["h1", "h2"],
 "body": [{"h1": "a1", "h2":"a2"},
          {"h1": "b1", "h2":"b2"},
           ...                   ]
}
```

Now I would like to transform this one into an (orderable table) with angular. I tried:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="header in data.headers">{{ header }}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="line in data.body">
        <td ng-repeat="(key, val) in line">{{ val | date : "dd.MM.yy" }}</td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Of course it does not work, as objects do not have a key order in javascript.
Is there a simple way to sort the line by headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this very simple:

```
<tr ng-repeat="line in data.body">
    <td ng-repeat="header in data.headers">{{ line[header] | date : "dd.MM.yy" }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @N.V.Prasad No, orderBy sorts by field of iterated objects. But in our case lines have no 'header' field.